# How to run electric match and microcontroller from a single power supply

Tags: power

We have a fairly large system that's been built up over the years for running a fireworks show from a computer (see [here](https://launchpad.codeplex.com/) for the first generation software and hardware) using a pretty simple XBee-based wireless system.  I'm in the process of working on a replacement system and I'm trying to tackle one of the annoying things in the current system...which is current.

Ideally I'd like to be able to run both the local microcontroller (I'm using a version of the XBee that has an on-board Freescale) and fire the electric matches with a single power supply.  The problem, of course, is that firing the matches takes all current away from the uc, causing it to reset.  I've tried thinking about how to isolate the matches, which are essentially shorts in the circuit from the uc, but I'm afraid I'm woefully out of my depth in this area.  I'm assuming some capacitors would be involved but I don't know exactly what it would look like.  The firing current of an electric match is around 1A and extremely rapid.  Ideally we'd have up to 16 matches per system.  Bonus points if the solution could also be used to power an on-demand flash :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You not only need to store enough energy to run the MCU, you also need to prevent it from being used up by the match as well.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faVAk1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This circuit will allow the supply to charge up the capacitor, but not allow it to feed back into the supply when the match is triggered. Note that the voltage to the MCU will be reduced by the forward voltage of the diode.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm not sure I entirely understand though...where does the match come in to this?  I'm currently firing the match using a MOSFET, which I think you're suggesting would source from behind the diode?

Comment: Yes, the match would draw from the supply as normal.

Answer (score 1):

You need a separate power supply system for your electric matches, entirely isolated from the microcontroller. Treat the matches as high-current loads and drive them with power transistors or MOSFETs in **low-side driver** configurations. Connect the low-side drivers to the microcontroller via **optocouplers**

Comment: Thanks, I am using MOSFETs to drive the matches.  I'm not familiar enough with optocouplers to understand what the advantage of that would be.  Will that help to isolate the MCU?

Comment: @Jeff The optocoupler will electrically isolate your microcontroller from the high-current supply that fires the matches. The signal is conveyed by light; an LED lights up and makes a phototransistor conduct. That phototransistor is used to trigger the MOSFET. All the microcontroller needs to do is light up the LED in the first place. There need be no connection between the microcontroller PSU and the match PSU.

Answer (score 0):

A fairly large decoupling cap right at your microcontroller power pin.

Without knowing how big of a dip your power rail takes and for how long or how often, it's hard to suggest a decent one. You could get away with just a 100 or 1000 uf or both in parallel.

An oscilloscope to measure and graph the actual drop is required.

Comment: 16A through a short circuit is going to need one hell of a decoupling cap...

Comment: @ignacio the microcontroller only needs a fraction of that.

Comment: Is this different than @ignacio's suggestion?

Comment: @Jeff: It is in that it doesn't include a diode. Instead it depends on the inductance of the wires to prevent the matches from draining the capacitor too quickly.

Comment: Hm...well diodes are cheap :)